# How to launch multiple remote process and wait when all process are completed

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ssh

I need to launch multiple Python scripts in multiple virtual machines.

I would like to run the scripts and exit. Once the scripts have completed they should send a message back.

My attempt so far is:

```
outputs = {}
threads = []

(0..(@number_of_vms - 1)).each do |vm|
  threads << Thread.new do

    Net::SSH.start(address[vm], user) do |session|
      cmd = 'python /media/sf_openfoam/gen_cfd_results.py'
      outputs[address[vm]] = session.exec!(cmd)

    end
  end
end
threads.each {|thr| thr.join }
```

This works, but it waits for the scripts to finish.
I  tried to remove the final `join`, but then Ruby exits and the scripts either don't run or only one of them does and it hangs.

Any advice?

Comment: You have to use `join` as you found. As a recommendation, you need to keep track of the response of each system you connect to. I'd suggest a hash with keys for each host, but that's your implementation choice. Imagine the problem diagnosing the problem if you don't know which machine failed. Also, I'd use `address.each` to loop, but I might be naive.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the code to include your suggestion. It's very weird because this code works as expected on my local VMs, but it practically exits immediately on my other 4 VMs on amazon. Is there any timeout issue?

Comment: Forget the issue on amazon. My mistake. If you answer the question I will accept it. Thanks